# Geometry is not highlighting in edit mode in 3.6 or 3.6.1

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

I’m having a big problem with the 3.6 series of updates…or maybe it’s me. I have a character I have been working on for an animation project. I have upgraded to version 3.6 then 3.6.1 but, during this time I was primarily working on hair and learning its intricacies and options along with clothing so, I didn’t touch the main mesh. Now I am trying another approach using weight painting for hair, and found that I can’t see anything I attempt to edit on the main character body. When I go into edit mode I can’t highlight a vertex, edge, or face for editing, I can move it, delete, etc but, I can’t see what is selected, nothing highlights so I’m working blind. I also can’t see any of my seams. I keep a series of versions of the character running in case of trouble (like this) and went back to older versions and still have the same problem. Then I loaded back version 3.5.1 and everything works fine, I can edit the character as usual. In version 3.6.1 I have no control of seeing what character geometry I’m working with, a little tough for weight painting or group selecting. In 3.5.1 I do so, I loaded 3.6.0 on another machine (Blender won’t let me install 3.6.0 and 3.6.1 on the same machine), same result so it seems to have started with my upgrading to 3.6. I put 3.5 and 3.6/61 on side by side screens and went systematically through just about every setting and menu to see if I bumped something or if something new was added that caused it but everything seems to line up. Next, in 3.6.1, I copied the main mesh, slid it over and converted it to mesh, all my seams were back and I could see the hi-lite of whatever I wanted to edit, basically back to normal except, all my Shape Keys disappeared. I can rework but, if it is not necessary because I missed a setting, I’d rather correct that and keep going as before. One other thing, I also tried deleting all the hair and empties for the hair, to see if that might be where a glitch was, but it wasn’t. Anybody see something I don’t? Thanks.

[image]
In 3.5.1 everything working fine, you can see the block select highlighted and the face lit to extrude, seams are shown too. So far so good.

[image]

In 3.6.0 geometry selected to edit does not highlight. I clicked on a vertex but nothing showed, I was still able to pull it out but I am running blind. If I try to select a group of vertex, edges, or faces, I have no idea if I have it selected or not. A little tough to vertex paint or weight paint, or just generally work.

[image]

Same thing in 3.6.1, I can select by individual geometry or group but I don't know what I have till I move it so, tough to do anything else with it.

[image]

In 3.6.1 I copied the mesh, converted, and everything is back, seams, visual for editing geometry BUT, all my Shape Keys are gone.